# Style guide and setup for AMPscript

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, ampscript

Long time coder first time AMPer! I have some specific questions which I can't find answers readily for in the documentation or generally:

1. Code style guide/conventions
2. A guide or advice on setting up local development environment for testing AMP, or is that not possible?
3. Is there versioning and granular permissions within marketing cloud that will provide some sort of rollback/protection?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Here's a link to start. I suggest reading through the [Syntax Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/syntaxGuide.htm) & [Function Reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/functions.htm)
2. There is no way to setup a local environment. The easiest way to test is to setup a Dropbox account and put a Treatascontent link in your landing page so when you save locally it updates Dropbox and then your landing page. Beats saving/publishing every time.
3. There is no rollback/protection in Marketing Cloud. Backup your work locally with versioning if necessary.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks @hamish-wilson! 

I'd found the reference docs but nothing that mentions style specifics e.g. casing of variable names for example. I've inherited some AMP that is all in CAPS and it'r really difficult to read. Is there such a thing?

Comment: AMPscript is not case sensitive. I find it easier to read if the functions and statements are in caps or follow a format though.